# FInd the values between a starting and ending time

Tags: python

I have a variable start_time and end_time and another value called confirmed_time. I need to  do a match that the confirmed_time is in between start_time and end_time. How i will find out. The time is in following format:

```
starting_time = "Jan 25 10:00:00"
ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59"
```

confirmed_time is also in the same format.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Parse them and compare. Why use a regex?

Comment: Use your language's Date/Time functionalities. Regexes are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the date and time as a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) object and them compare them. Note, its important that the format's of each of these time remains the same

```
>>> starting_time = "Jan 25 10:00:00"
>>> ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59"
>>> confirmed_time = "Jan 25 11:11:11"
>>> starting_time_dt = datetime.strptime(starting_time,"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> ending_time_dt   = datetime.strptime(ending_time,"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> confirmed_time_dt   = datetime.strptime(confirmed_time,"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> if starting_time_dt <= confirmed_time_dt <= ending_time_dt:
    print "Within ...."


Within ....
>>> confirmed_time = "Jan 24 11:11:11"
>>> confirmed_time_dt   = datetime.strptime(confirmed_time,"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> if starting_time_dt <= confirmed_time_dt <= ending_time_dt:
    print "Within ...."


>>>
```

Comment: @just_in: Look at the linked docs for `strptime`; they explain how to describe any date format you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Use dateutil to parse the values and convert them to datetime. Then check that your confirmed_time is in the required interval.

Comment: Why use a third-party module if the builtin `datetime` can already handle all that?

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- because in 90+ % of the cases it lets you avoid the `%` nonsense :)

Answer (score 0):

datetime module will be of help

```
In [41]: starting_time = "Jan 25 10:00:00"

In [42]: datetime.datetime.strptime(starting_time, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
Out[42]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 25, 10, 0)

In [43]: s = datetime.datetime.strptime(starting_time, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")

In [44]: ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59"

In [45]: e = datetime.datetime.strptime(ending_time, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")

In [46]: e
Out[46]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 26, 20, 6, 59)

In [47]: confirm_time   = "Jan 26 12:00:00"

In [48]: c = datetime.datetime.strptime(confirm_time, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")

In [49]: if s < c < e:
   ....:     print True
   ....:
True
```

Check these [formats](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.52/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm) which can be used while converting string to datetime object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install and use the [dateutlil module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), as it makes parsing dates much easier.

```
from dateutil import parser

s_time = "Jan 25 10:00:00"
e_time = "Jan 26 20:06:59"
f_time = "Jan 25 12:10:00"

def example(conf, start, end):
    p = parser.parse
    return p(start) < p(conf) < p(end)

print example(f_time, s_time, e_time)
#output: True
```

`parser.parse` can handle most of the even obscure formats:

```
In[21]: parser.parse("Sat Jan 26 00:31:17 UTC 2013")
Out[21]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 26, 0, 31, 17, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isDateBetween(starting_time, ending_time, confirmed_time):
        pattern = '%b %d %H:%M:%S'

        startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(starting_time, pattern)
        endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(ending_time, pattern)
        confirmedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(confirmed_time, pattern)

        return startDate <= confirmedDate <= endDate

print isDateBetween("Jan 25 10:00:00", "Jan 26 20:06:59", "Jan 27 12:20:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import datetime as dt

starting_time = "Jan 25 10:00:00"
ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59"
confirmed_time = "Jan 26 08:10:01"
fmt="%b %d %H:%M:%S"

print (dt.datetime.strptime(starting_time,fmt) < 
       dt.datetime.strptime(confirmed_time,fmt) < 
       dt.datetime.strptime(ending_time,fmt))
```

Note that with no year specified, `datetime` defaults to 1900. The lack of the year is then somewhat ambiguous however. What if:

```
starting_time = "Dec 26 10:00:00"
ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59"     # the following year or the same year? 
confirmed_time = "Jan 02 08:10:01"
```

*Edit*

You can handle years (as in your comment) by changing the [input format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) used by strptime:

```
import datetime as dt

starting_time = "Dec 25 10:00:00 UTC 2012"
ending_time   = "Jan 26 20:06:59 UTC 2013"
confirmed_time = "Jan 02 08:10:01 UTC 2013"
fmt="%b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y"

print (dt.datetime.strptime(starting_time,fmt) < 
       dt.datetime.strptime(confirmed_time,fmt) < 
       dt.datetime.strptime(ending_time,fmt))
```

Comment: what about if the date is in the follwing format " Sat Jan 26 00:31:17 UTC 2013"

Comment: @just_in: If you use that date format, you will remove the potential ambiguity. See my edit.